# sql query not matching the string literal stored in variable

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I am facing a problem while executing this `sql` query. The variable `combo_sel` doesn't seem to be replaced in the `sql` query.

Could you help me find the error?

```
String combo_sel = String.valueOf(station_type.getSelectedItem());
sql="Select reporting_date as REPORTING_DATE,for_date as FOR_DATE,outage_date as OUTAGE_DATE,outage_time as OUTAGE_TIME,stat_detail as STATION_DETAILS,res_date as RESTORATION_DATE,rest_time as RESTORATION_TIME,rest_reason as RESTORATION_REASON from " + table_sel+" where for_date='" + date1 + "' and stat_detail ="+ combo_sel ;
```

Comment: Learn to use parameters rather than munging values into query strings.

Comment: `stat_detail = ' "+ combo_sel+" ' " ;`

Comment: Yes, that is an option. But I wanted to know how to fix this.

Comment: That works ! Thanks ! @Sanket Makani

Comment: Okay so delete the question then! :)